# Slimerjs with exec linux centos 6

Tags: php, linux, exec, slimerjs

I just installed Slimerjs and no results on the web.

the slimerjs is found and commands like -help etc output like they should:
 `exec('/usr/bin/slimerjs -help'.' 2>&1',$out,$ret);`

but this line does not work

```
       exec('/usr/bin/slimerjs /var/www/html/capture.js'.' 2>&1',$out,$ret); var_dump($ret, $out);
```

outputs only int(1); and nothing more. no errors in logs, it does not work. I can write everything I like if the bath is correct the output is always int(1).

Thank you

Comment: it seems that it's because /usr/bin/xvfb-run is not added. `exec('/usr/bin/xvfb-run /usr/bin/slimerjs /var/www/html/capture.js'.' 2>&1',$out,$ret);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had same issue now, just a minute ago. But I am using a combination of Casperjs with Slimerjs engine (Casperjs is a great tool for working with your slimerjs and phantomjs scripts, in a friendlier enviroment programming).

The working php script:

```
<?php 

putenv("PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/bin/phantomjs");
putenv("CASPERJS_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/bin/casperjs");
putenv("SLIMERJS_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/bin/slimerjs");
putenv("DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH");

echo passthru('/usr/bin/xvfb-run /usr/local/bin/casperjs --ssl-protocol=any --proxy-type=auto --engine=slimerjs casperjsscript.js 2>&1'); 

?>
```

You could perhaps check to include some of the paths, as indicated seen in my script and make a few changes, or just install Casperjs :)